# can't filter logcat in android app

Tags: android

I am working on an app and have the following code to display the app in a textview, but the only command that it's displaying is `logcat -d`.

I want it to filter stuff that are tag with `dalvikvm`. I tried `logcat -s dalvikvm` but my app does not display any log information on the device.

Here is my code.

```
    try {
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -s dalvikvm");
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

        StringBuilder log=new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
          log.append(line);
        }
        TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textlog);
        tv.setText(log.toString());
      } catch (IOException e) {
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: First step is to try logcat without the program--just on the command line with adb. This will let you experiment with what works.

Answer (score 0):

Examination of logcat.cpp confirms my suspicion that any error messages from the program itself will be written to stderr - only the actual log messages go to stdout.

So if anything is wrong with your attempt, you would see nothing at all.  A very likely thing that would be wrong would be not having the read logs permission in your app manifest; without this, logcat run by your app, and hence under your app's userid, will not be able to access the log buffer.  And it's complaint would be to stderr rather than stdout.

Two recommendations:

- try opening process.getErrorStream() instead, and see if you get an error message.
- make sure you have the read logs manifest permission